# JQuery Mobile Auto complete issue in safari (IPAD) browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, safari

I an trying implement auto complete function for customer code.

Can anyone tell me why this below code is not working in safari(IPAD) browser?

It worked perfectly in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    

$("#mainPage").on("pageshow", function (e) {

var sugList = $("#suggestions");

$("#CustomerCode").on("input", function (e) {
var text = $(this).val();

if (text.length < 1) {
    sugList.html("");
    sugList.listview("refresh");
} 
else {
      $.ajax({ cache: false,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: '/Lookup/GetCustomer',
      data: { filterCustomerCode: text },
      success: function (res, code) {
      var str = "";
      for (var i = 0, len = res.length; i < len; i++) {
      str += '<li data-icon="arrow-r"><a href="/home/index?CustomerCode=' + res[i].Code + '" >' + res[i].Code + '</a></li>';
}
sugList.html(str);
sugList.listview("refresh");
console.dir(res);
},
async: true
});
}
});

});

</script>
```

Many Thanks,

Maduranga

Comment: there is a problem in safari (IPAD and with IOS 6.0)